# Embedding video on this site is forbidden. Watch on Odnoklassniki

Tags: html, iframe, embed, blogger

I am trying to embed this code on my blogspot, after I publish I get this error -

> "Embedding video on this site is forbidden. Watch on Odnoklassniki"

The code snippet -

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//ok.ru/videoembed/916692339423" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding the full url of the video it works

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://ok.ru/videoembed/916692339423" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok.ru has an embed widget that works for this.  Just substitute your video URL as shown below (this should work with or without the protocol defined at the start of the URL)

```
<script>
!function (d, id, did, st) {
  var js = d.createElement("script");
  js.src = "https://connect.ok.ru/connect.js";
  js.onload = js.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete") {
    if (!this.executed) {
      this.executed = true;
      setTimeout(function () {
        OK.CONNECT.insertContentWidget(id,did,st);
      }, 0);
    }
  }};
  d.documentElement.appendChild(js);
}(document,"ok_content_widget","https://ok.ru/videoembed/916692339423",'{"topicTextIsFull":1}');
</script>
```